# SQL UPDATE updates more columns than the number of columns set in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called notifier with 11 columns :

```
CREATE TABLE `notifier` (    
  `NUM_UTILISATEUR` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
  `NUM_NOTIFICATION` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
  `LU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,    
  `DATE_NOTIFIER` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,    
  `NUM_PENSEE` int(32) NOT NULL,    
  `NUM_CONTRIBUTION` int(32) NOT NULL,    
  `NUM_COMMENTAIRE` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
  `CODE_NOTIF` int(11) NOT NULL,    
  `VU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,    
  `DATE_VU` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',    
  `DATE_LU` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And I want to update only 2 columns : VU and DATE_LU. For that, I ran this mysql query :

```
UPDATE notifier 
SET VU=1, DATE_LU = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
WHERE NUM_UTILISATEUR=130 
AND NUM_PENSEE = 113 
AND CODE_NOTIF=2 
AND NUM_CONTRIBUTION=439 
AND NUM_COMMENTAIRE=600"
```

But It updates 3 columns : VU, DATE_VU and DATE_LU, instead of the 2 (VU, DATE_LU) I wanted! I even replace date('Y-m-d H:i:s') by NOW() but the issue remains

Any idea of what is going on ?

Comment: Is there a trigger in your db?

Comment: Not at all. I've no trigger in my db

Comment: maybe `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` issue?

Comment: No. My issue still remains when I remove `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Are you running this query straight from phpmyadmin? Because at first glance If you have shown everything, if there are no TRIGGER and no `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the problem can only be in the application code and not the DB

Comment: I ran the query both on my phpmyadmin and my php application. But the issue still remain.